# Can't read json file in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I am trying to create a simple laravel crud, where I will be able to use a json file as database instead of MySQL. But it's returning "null" when I am trying to fetch data from the json file located in "resource/lang" folder .

The output is :

[Please click to view the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjmzR.png)

My codes from controller :

```
    public function getjson(){

    $json = file_get_contents('../resources/lang/test.json');
    $gravatar = json_decode($json);
    dd($gravatar);
   }
```

My json file (locating at resources/lang/test.json)

```
[
{   
    "id": 1,
    "product_name": "Apple",
    "per_item_price": "10",
    "product_quanity": "4",
    "total_price": "50",
},

{
  
    "id": 2,
    "product_name": "Apple",
    "per_item_price": "10",
    "product_quanity": "4",
    "total_price": "50",
},
]
```

And The route from web.php is :

```
Route::get('/getjson', 'App\Http\Controllers\Master@getjson');
```

[image: test.json file screenshot]

[image: dd($json result screenshot)]

Comment: what happens if you `dd($json);` or `dd(json_last_error())`?

Comment: for dd(json_last_error()), It returns 0, and for dd($json), I am getting ` """
{
    "product_name": "Apple",
    "per_item_price": "per_item_price",
    "product_quanity": "product_quanity",
    "total_price": "total_price",
}
""" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with JSON in  test.json. Because it has a trailing comma.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "product_name": "Apple",
        "per_item_price": "10",
        "product_quanity": "4",
        "total_price": "50"
    },

    {

        "id": 2,
        "product_name": "Apple",
        "per_item_price": "10",
        "product_quanity": "4",
        "total_price": "50"
    }
]
```

Remove unwanted comma after total price and end of last object. Language folder used for multi-language purpose. So I suggest you to use storage folder to save this file

For accessing storage files `storage/app/test.json`

```
$json = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::get("test.json");
    $gravatar = json_decode($json);
    dd($gravatar);
```

**Updated**
As above comment by @shaedrich.

To check JSON error

```
$json = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::get("test.json");
    $gravatar = json_decode($json);
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
            break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
            break;
    }
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code, still giving the same result ...

Comment: i have tested it .it works fine.check again once

Comment: i have updated to access storage file path.

Comment: still returning null lol, I have put test.json in storage/app folder

Comment: i have updated my answer.so you can see erorrs

Comment: adding file to storage doesn't fix error from json file. I suggested to keep files in necessary folder

Comment: ok I am checking again, Please check the answer I have given for Shaedrich

Comment: can you take screenshot of test.json content.want to see once.

Comment: it's saying - Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: yes.so you have not at  updated json what i have mentioned in answer.still you have trailing comma

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my test.json file, please check at the bottom of my question

Comment: i saw.it should work.still if you getting erorr  means difficult to tell since i have tested your json both lang and storage it works well after removing trailing comma

Comment: try once clearing cache and view file also

Comment: Still not working , but I really appreciate your support

Comment: dd($json); and comment result

Comment: please check the bottom of my question, I have shared the screenshot

Comment: It's returning the first file (I used before asking here, not the current one)

Comment: Thank you so much bro ! I mistakenly copied my same defected json file in storage instead the corrected one - sorry for that

Comment: @azim np :) .Even i curious why it didn't worked for you.any way glad to here you have solved your issue

Comment: can You help another issue , how to fetch data from that json file by id . thanks again

Comment: if you don't mind then i suggest you to open new issue.so some one can help you .